# Sleuth 3.0.3 doesn't work with Kafka in kafka logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

Iam new to sleuth.

I added the sleuth dependecny as follows.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and made the corresponding changes in log pattern

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%tid] [%t] [%X{traceId},%X{spanId}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
```

for normal logs I get the traceId and spanId as below

```
18:54:28.876 [42] [http-nio-8082-exec-2] [04287c5af43cc1d2,04287c5af43cc1d2] INFO  - ajax event received
```

when the data is send to kafka it is shown as below.

```
18:54:30.763 [72] [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] [,] INFO  - event successfully send to kafka topic at time 1645709070763
```

The kafka producer is as shown below.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducer {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

    private final ProducerConfiguration producerConfiguration;

    public Future<RecordMetadata> produceEvents(GenericRecord genericRecord, String topic, String sessionId) {

        Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfiguration.getProducerProperties());

        ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
                topic, sessionId, genericRecord
        );

        Future<RecordMetadata> data = producer.send(producerRecord,
                (RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) ->{
                if (exception == null) {
                    log.info("event successfully send to kafka topic at time {}", System.currentTimeMillis());
                } else {
                    log.info(exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
        );

        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
        return data;
    }
}
```

The producer configuration.

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProducerConfiguration {

    private final Properties producerProperties;

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrapserver}")
    private String bootstrapServer;
    @Value("${kafka.acks}")
    private String acks;
    @Value("${kafka.retries}")
    private String retries;
    @Value("${kafka.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection}")
    private String maxInFlightRequestsPerConnection;
    @Value("${kafka.enable.idempotence}")
    private String enableIdempotence;

    public ProducerConfiguration(Properties producerProperties){
        this.producerProperties = producerProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    private void setProperties(){
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acks);
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, maxInFlightRequestsPerConnection);
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, enableIdempotence);
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer .class.getName());
        this.producerProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroSerializer .class.getName());
        this.producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, Collections.singletonList(TracingProducerInterceptor.class));

    }
}
```

Iam not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: You'll need to show your producer configuration class. Specifically, how are you adding the Brave Kafka interceptor for adding tracing to it? Also, doesn't it need an autowire annotation?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I have added the ProducerConfiguration above. Im not autowiring rather using the constructor injection. For now I haven't added any brave kafka interceptor and not sure how to add it.

Comment: Adding a line for `ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES` would be a start. https://github.com/openzipkin-contrib/brave-kafka-interceptor Also, you don't need to manually define all those `${kafka.}` attributes since Spring-Kafka will automatically set those if you have `spring.kafka.producer.` config section

Comment: @OneCricketeer as per your suggestion I tried adding the interceptor class config and the output is still the same. I have updated the question with the config you mentioned.

Comment: My only other thought is that the Kafka client uses a different logger context that isn't shared with Spring

Comment: Specifically, `LogManager` is from `java.util.logging`? Kafka uses log4j, not JUL, and Spring should either be using logback or log4j2, by default

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is there anyway to override that, Iam using log4j2 in the project and kafka logs also seems to pick the same pattern and changes in the pattern layout whenever I change in the log4j2.xml

Comment: You seem to be using `LogManager`, which is different from `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`

Comment: @OneCricketeer  the log manager Im using is from `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
`

Comment: Okay, well, like I said, it's definitely an MDC problem since that's what the `%X` log property is for. I've personally never used it with Kafka, and I still think the issue is that Kafka uses log4j 1.x which may not be able to use MDC contexts

Comment: @OneCricketeer I looked at the kafka message headers and `spanId` and `traceId` seems to be there. Do you have any idea on how to override the kafka log4j1 to log4j2

Comment: The record headers are separate from any logger context... You'd have to do something like this https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker/blob/master/pom.xml#L164-L196